# Windows .NET / Win32 UI development

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I've been battling trying to figure out how to visually create a table. It's a weird table that is sortable by column but only rows are selectable.

For people using uTorrent it looks something like this

[image]

I can't find this anywhere in Visual Studio! If it's not avialiable, how would I go about creating it myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a regular [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) with the [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx) property = `Details` with [`FullRowSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx).

Comment: Yup.  The sorting has to be added.  ListView.ListViewItemSorter property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control.